# Missing options: No fork, clone, commits, branches

Tags: azure-devops

I was given access to Azure Devops for a project and added to the Project Administrators group but I don't have access to some options like fork, clone, commits, branches. It is something related to permissions? The Azure admin told me she already gave me all needed permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a TFVC repo. The options you're looking for are Git features. Refer to the documentation for the differences between TFVC and Git.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't realize that, thanks!